# Run PDO SQLite Query On In-Memory Database On Github Actions

Tags: sqlite, pdo, phpunit, github-actions, database-testing

I use PHPUnit to test by PDO wrapper. One of my tests is an integration test that proves that the abstraction layer produces the right syntax, or binds `PDOStatement` in the right way, etc. For this, I use an in-memory SQLite database, and declare `ext-pdo_sqlite` as a dev-dependency of my project.

When Github Actions runs a build, dependencies all get installed, hinting that `pdo_sqlite` is present on the system. This is further confirmed by the fact that the connection succeeds. However, when I run an insert query to set up my database, I get the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: TRUE
```

The query looks like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO `persons` (`id`, `name`, `dob`, `weight`, `is_dev`, `teeth`) VALUES (NULL, 'Anton', '1987-11-03', 71.3, TRUE, 31)
```

Table creation is done with PDO like this:

```php
$pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE `$tableName` (`id` int(6) PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(255), `dob` datetime, `weight` float(5), `is_dev` bool, `teeth` int(2))");
```

This only manifests on CI, and local tests pass fine - even on the same PHP version as CI.

Any ideas? Am I just missing something in the syntax? Could it be that GH Actions has only a dummy implementation of SQLite or something?

**Note**: This is an open source project, and you can see everything, including the failing build, in [`dhii/pdo-query#1`](https://github.com/Dhii/pdo-query/pull/1).

Comment: Is the database missing? Is there a `CREATE DATABASE` step before the INSERT?

Comment: Yep. I added it to the question now, thanks! Also, like I mentioned, the same tests run and pass fine locally, so I would assume the difference is in the environment. That's why I was thinking that maybe GHA's SQLite is somehow different.

Comment: Added link to pull request also, if someone wants to take a closer look.